# Database timezone not using TZ

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a timestamp column 'submitted_on' with default as now().
I have set the heroku TZ to my zone and added a php user ini with the same timezone.

But the database is still using UTC timezone. I see this when I ran this sql:
`show timezone`;

Is there a fix? Or this is how heroku databases work? Also I'm using free dynos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a `TZ` config var only affects the Dynos environment, as the database is located on a different machine, it has no effect.

Generally speaking, you should always keep servers clocks running on UTC, store all times in UTC, and perform any timezone/locale changes in your application framework.

Comment: I have changed the code to include the timestamp manually instead. It's just a vanilla php application.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `timezone` is determined when the database cluster is created.

You can either change the value in `postgresql.conf`, or you can use `ALTER SYSTEM` as a superuser to change the value.

I don't know if Heroku allows you either of these options.

Comment: I have looked into it. I couldn't find a way to change the conf file.

Comment: Can you remove the database cluster and recreate it with the new system timezone?